# Prove $\{f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[[x,y]] \mid f(\zeta_n x,\zeta_n^{-1}y) = f(x,y)\}$ is not isomorphic to the formal series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Suppose that $\zeta_n$ is a primitive n-th root of $1$.
>
> Let $R$ be $\{f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[[x,y]] \mid f(\zeta_n x,\zeta_n^{-1}y) = f(x,y)\}$.
>
> Try to prove that $R$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

**My Work**: Assume that $f(x,y)=\sum a_{i,j}x^iy^j$. Then $f(\zeta_n x,\zeta_n^{-1}y)=f(x,y)$ implies that $a_{i,j}=0$ when $n\not\mid i-j$. Thus $$f(x,y)=\sum_{in+j\geq 0}(xy)^jx^{in}.$$ Then I can't go any further. I think we need some properties of $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$.

Any one has some advice or ideas?

And there is another question, let $S=\{f[x,y]\in \mathbb{C}[[x,y]]\mid f[\zeta_nx,\zeta_ny]=f[x,y]\}$. Try to prove that $S$ is not isomorphic to $R$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

Comment: Your calculation should show that $R=\mathbb{C}[[x^n,xy,y^n]]$( I am assuming $n>1$) and this ring can not be generated as a power series ring in two variables, needs three generators.

Comment: But your generators are not algebraic independent.

Comment: Look at the smallest (say, in lexicographic ordering) non-zero terms, $A$ and $B$, of the image in $R$, of $x$ and $y$ by an assumed isomorphism. Every element of $C[[x,y]]$ is of the form $c+xM+yN$, with $c$ constant. Therefore the smallest non-constant term of all the elements of the image in $R$ of the assumed isomorphism will be terms that are divisible by $A$ or $B$. There are no pair of non-constant terms in R that divide all non-constant terms, since there are none that do so for $x^n,xy,y^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the three rings $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$, $R$, and $S$ is local, with a unique maximal ideal consisting of power series with constant term $0$. For each ring, I will compute the vector space dimension of the quotient of the ring by the square of the maximal ideal. The three dimensions will be distinct, which proves the three rings are pairwise non-isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

For $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$, the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is the set of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $i+j\geq 1$, so $\mathfrak{m}^2$ is power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $i+j\geq 2$. The quotient $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has a basis $1$, $x$, $y$, so is $3$-dimensional.

The ring $R$ consists of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $n|i-j$. The maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is the set of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $i+j\geq 1$ and $n|i-j$. By taking pairwise products of such monomials, we can get monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfying either $i$, $j\geq 2$, or $i\geq 1$, $j\geq n$, or $j\geq 1$, $i\geq n$. The quotient $R/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has a basis $1$, $xy$, $x^n$, $y^n$, so is $4$-dimensional.

The ring $S$ consists of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $n|i+j$. The maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is the set of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $n|i+j$ and $i+j\geq n$, so $\mathfrak{m}^2$ is the set of power series whose monomials $x^iy^j$ satisfy $n|i+j$ and $i+j\geq 2n$. The quotient $S/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has a basis 
$$
1,x^n, x^{n-1}y, x^{n-2}y^2,\ldots,xy^{n-1},y^n,
$$
so is $(n+2)$-dimensional.